HTMLElement.focus(): What is considered as "visible"?
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/focus
https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interaction.html#focusing-steps
When calling the focus() method on an HTMLElement, the developer needs to make sure that the element is "visible" in the DOM, otherwise the focus will fail and will either do nothing or return to the body element.
This fact notably appears to be missing from the MDN page on focus(), and I can't figure out what to make of the associated WHATWG spec.
My understanding is that, to receive focus, the element must:

Not have visibility: hidden, using window.getComputedStyle(element).visibility !== 'hidden'
Not have display: none
Have dimensions element.getBoundingClientRect().width > 0 && element.getBoundingClientRect().height > 0
Be in the document flow element.offsetParent !== null
Have a tabindex

Without confirming the spec, I can't confirm if the above is correct.

Also not display: none

I think what you're looking for is the definition of "focusable area": https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interaction.html#focusable-area

@Barmar thank you, forgot about that one, updated the post :) I'll look into focusable-area and get back to you.
